# Android Slow GridView

Tags: android, performance, gridview, android-fragments

I'm new to Android Development, I ran into a performance issue. When my GridView has too many items it becomes kinda slow. Is there any way to make it behave a little faster?

Here is the code im using:

Adapter:

```
public class CharactersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int screenSize;
private int columns;
// Constructor

public CharactersAdapter(Context c,int screenSize) {
    this.screenSize=screenSize;
    mContext = c;
}

public CharactersAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return charPics.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {

    return charPics[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView imageView;
    this.columns=mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_columns);
    if (convertView == null) {

        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(screenSize /this.columns,screenSize      /this.columns));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(charPics[i]));
    return imageView;
}}
```

Fragment

```
public class CharacterFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_character, container, false);
    GridView gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new CharactersAdapter(getActivity(),screenWidth));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CharacterActivity.class);
            // Pass image index
            i.putExtra("pos", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?....

Comment: if you have big images then you will notice it being slow when you set the image to the imageview

Comment: The grid has 51 images of approximately 50Kb

Comment: I dont mean big as in image size I mean big as in image dimensions

Comment: So is it normal to be a little bit slow?

Comment: Well yes and no, Yes in the sense of how you are doing it being on the UI thread, No as in you should handle big images correctly, see here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: As an side note, you can just use `imageView.setImageResource(charPics[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Picasso library to load images. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I really recomend you to use the Holder Pattern there, in it you save the view you create to be reused and save memory what will deliver more performance, [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder) is a very good tutorial on it. Also for the images loading you could use Universal Image Loader that will make the Image loading [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) asynchronously so your UI Thread dont come up slow. Good Luck

Comment: `ViewHolder` pattern here would actually be *less* efficient. There are no `findViewById()` calls -- it's just an `ImageView`.